# Unit testing methods that require several dependencies / other objects

Tags: unit-testing, oop

I am trying to unit test a method that calculates a reward, based on odds that are defined in the same class as where the method lives, and a dice result, that is generated in another class, GameTurn.

```
private final double[] ODDS = {0, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.5};

public double getOutcome(int dieResult)
{
    return bet * ODDS[dieResult-1];
}
```

In the class GameTurn, I set the number of dice that should be used and in the Die class, I set the number of die sides.

What I want to get out of the test, is to check that the ODDS arrays length corresponds to 
the number of dice * diesides.

My idea is that I test the getOutcome method, but in order for me to test it, I need to instantiate several other objects and therefore it strikes me:

1. *Is it normal when unit testing, that in order to test a method, several objects needs to be instantiated and I practically need to run half the program?*
2. *Is it because of bad OOP design, that my unit tests require these objects?*

An overview of the situation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those question are usually hard to answer but I will try to give some tump roles that will help you decide

1. Unit test should be esay to understand what you are testing - should test 1 case at a test
2. If your class need to have all your application and setting - you might have design issues.
3. The simplest ways to overcome that are :better design , Interfaces, Injection
4. If you depend on other 3rd party services - use mocking ,so you can control the response and test edge cases
5. Depending on your platform - you can use Mockito or build your own mocking
6. Something it's make sense that the test class inherit from you class - this way you can test non-public methods

For more details can check out this [good Unit Testing Guidelines](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/community/testing.html)

Hope this help

Comment: So 1 case could involve more then just testing the functionality in the method. As when a method requires other methods, they will be tested along and can be seen as one test case? I had an understanding that unit tests, should test as small pieces of code as possible

Comment: unit test should be for 1 method - but it can test other methods as a side effect,but you should have other unit test for the other methods. I idea is that when unit test fail - you know exactly what is the problem. there are some unit test that test all your code (like e2e test that run all your code, for example strom local cluster that run all your topology in memory)

Comment: Thank you. What you explained, coupled with the link, have made unit testing more clear to me.